# Web API 2 returns 401 when hosted on IIS and return 200 when set authentication to anonymous

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a WebApi project , which returns some data , this works fine when we query through the URL , but returns 401 when i invoke it from my console app. 
this project has been hosted in IIS 8 and i need this to run under windows authentication. If i set it to anonymous authentication then works fine,  but gives error to windows auth mode. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include WebApiConfig.cs file in the question..

Comment: make sure you have added `<authentication mode="Windows" />` under `system.web` of your application's `app.config`

Comment: `works fine when we query through the URL , but returns 401 when i invoke it from my console app` - is your credentials saved in the browser? try running it under incognito mode and check for the status code.

Answer (score 3):

Check [HTTP Status Codes RFC](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) ...`401` stands for `Unauthorized Access` means while invoking from your console app you are not passing the `Authorization` header in your API request.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out(it has info on using windows authentication with web API):

https://www.codeproject.com/tips/996401/authenticate-webapis-with-basic-and-windows-authen